# Is anyone else currently getting a 500 error on all question pages?

Tags: support, 500-server-error

## Oops! Something Bad Happened!

Just me, or global issue?

I'm thoroughly enjoying the lolcatz apologies... ;).

Comment: Yep, I get the same on SO.

Comment: Just us (all of us) ;-)

Comment: I don't contest the possible-duplicateness.

Comment: Oh wow. I thought it was all struts questions. I was like "GAHHH!!! Struts templating! Slayer of all that it touches..."

Comment: Same for me. But I'm having an amusing time refreshing and cycling through the images!

Comment: @DamienPirsy, I feel like thousands of us constantly refreshing the error page isn't going to help anything

Comment: Yep me too. I just (possibly) found an answer to my problem and then... 500 -.-

Comment: Meh, I already saw them all I think, so no more refreshing by my side. Also, I take no responsability for the actions of those thousands!